# Are nullable operators valid within generic class?

Tags: generics, nullable, kotlin

Kotlin has pretty features (`?.` and `!!.`) handling nullable types. But this one just stroke me -- what if you don't know if you are dealing with nullable or non-nullable type? What if you have generics class `MyClass<T>`, then you just have some type `T` and that's it.

Does Kotlin allow to have "nullable" operators applied to generic type (`T` here), does the type can be made nullable **inside** class (like `T?`) and what if the class will be instantiated with nullable type -- like `MyClass<String?>`. Will it cause nullable of nullable (like pointer to pointer in C++ -- `**std::string`) type within `MyClass` type?

Comment: just type `T` is interpreted as `T: Any?` so there is not "just type `T`" because the compiler will see it as nullable.  You can use `T: Any` to define a different upper bounds that is not nullable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried it in the [Web Demo](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/enmcn6prnabvedfep67ktdcn1m/uonpv0fhromhvdchi8c03vsig9).

```
class MyClass<T>(val x: T) {
  fun foo() {
    println(x.toString())
  }

  fun fooSave() {
    println(x?.toString())
  }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  MyClass<String?>(null).fooSave()
  MyClass<String?>(null).foo()
}
```

It seems you can always apply the null-safe operator `?.`, even if the type isn't necessarily nullable.

On the other hand, you can bind the generic type parameter `T` to a nullable type, in my case `String?`, <strike>which in fact will produce a NullPointerException if you pass `null`</strike>.

**Edit**: Since the question was asked, the semantics of generic types without upper bound have changed. `T` is now interpreted as `T : Any?`. However the code above doesn't crash anymore. The reason is that the call `x.toString()` will call the extension function [`Any?.toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) which correctly handles `null`s.

If we change the code as follows

```
class MyClass<T : Any>(val x: T) {
  fun foo() {
    println(x.toString())
  }

  fun fooSave() {
    println(x?.toString())
  }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  MyClass<String?>(null).fooSave()
  MyClass<String?>(null).foo()
}
```

it now doesn't even compile, because we can't instantiate `T : Any` with `String?`. The call `x?.toString()` is also flagged with a warning, saying that the safe call is unnecessary.

Comment: Wow, if I could I would add more points for that link :-) Thank you very much. What's more -- you just discovered that explicit against null does not work really. Without generic you would have to write `!!.toString()` but with generics compiler does not know what `T` is and allow for implicit check.

Comment: On the second check, this example is special case, because `toString` is defined in root type. That is why (probably) it compiles in the first place -- any other method like `length` would require to add constraint to generics, and that mean you have to decide in advance for what type you write generic class -- nullable or not.

Comment: You're right. If I set T to extend any type, I can't bind it to a nullable type at all because T? doesn't extend T. Here's an example that doesn't compile: http://kotlin-demo.jetbrains.com/?publicLink=1174338469563409828491677856014

Comment: just type `T` is interpreted as `T: Any?` so there is not "just type `T`" because the compiler will see it as nullable.  You can use `T: Any` to define a different upper bounds that is not nullable.